# HTML line is overlap the circles

Tags: html, css

In actual I get I have 2 circles and line,that overlap it. 
I would like to have the circle at the beginning of the line and at the end.

Could you please help me to put the line between the circles.

[**Editable JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z7uqpe0h/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="time-slice row">
  <div class="date-time">
    <p class="date">Fri 28 Aug</p>
    <p class="time">10:00</p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-wrap">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="point-title">
    <span>
      <b>Kiev Borispol (KBP)</b>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="time-slice row">
  <div class="date-time">
    <p class="date">Fri 28 Aug</p>
    <p class="time">10:00</p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-wrap">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="point-title">
    <span>
      <b>Amsterdam (AMS)</b>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.time-slice {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin-left:20px;
  > * {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}

.circle {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-color: #29a8bb;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 32px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.circle-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  > .circle {
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
  }
}

.date-time {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

.date,
.time {
  max-width: 90px;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
}

.point-title {
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: could you be more specific? may be a screenshot of how you want it? Thanks.

Comment: I get smth like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaOqXO?editors=110

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `:not()` selector to not draw a line after the last circle.

```
.time-slice.row:not(:last-child)  .point-title
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyJqMW

Comment: Thanks for help! It looks nice, I like it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `position: relative` for `.time-slice` and `top` +`left` for `.circle-wrap` then add some margin, padding.

Demo: http://codepen.io/robinhuy/pen/OyJdGX

Answer (score 0):

Here you are copying less css from codepen.I just put correct css here.See the change.

```css
.time-slice {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
      -ms-flex-align: stretch;
          align-items: stretch;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.time-slice > * {
  padding: 20px;
}
.circle {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-color: #29a8bb;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 32px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.circle-wrap {
  position: absolute;
}
.circle-wrap > .circle {
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
}
.date-time {
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100px;
      -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100px;
          flex-basis: 100px;
}
.date,
.time {
  max-width: 90px;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.point-title {
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
}
```